# D3.js exit() not seeming to get updated information

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a Django View feeding a tablib CSV to D3.js. However, I'm finding that no matter how or where I use exit(), it isn't returning anything- and thusly, I cannot remove the old, unneeded elements, and everything just overlays on top of each other.

Any ideas? I based my code pretty hard off of [the basic Stacked Bar Chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208).

```
<div id="id_d3_canvas" class="d3_canvas_space">
</div>
<div>
<form id="id_date_form">
    <input id="id_date_small" name="date1" type="text" value="03-01-2012">
    <input id="id_date_large" name="date2" type="text" value="{% now 'n-j-Y' %}">
    <select name="our_people" multiple>
        {% for person in object_list %}
        <option value="{{ person.name }}" selected>{{ person.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
<button id="id_test_data_gather" class="btn btn-primary update_d3_csv">Update</button>
</div>

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}cms/js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#ff8c00"]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

    var svg = d3.select(".d3_canvas_space").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var date_info = $("#id_date_form").serialize(),
        initial_csv_url = "{% url blahblah %}?" + date_info;


    function updateMultiData(multi_csv_url) { 
        d3.csv(multi_csv_url, function(error, data) {
            color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Name"; }));

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                var y0 = 0;
                d.tasks = color.domain().map(function(category) { return {category: category, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[category]};});
                d.total_tasks = d.tasks[d.tasks.length - 1].y1;
            });

            data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Name; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total_tasks; })]);

            svg.selectAll(".name").data(data).exit().remove()

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Tasks");

            var person_name = svg.selectAll(".name")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Name) + ",0)"; });

            person_name.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d) { return d.tasks; })
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.category); });

            console.log(svg.selectAll(".name").data(data).exit());

            var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

            legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", width - 18)
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", 18)
                .style("fill", color);

            legend.append("text")
                .attr("x", width - 24)
                .attr("y", 9)
                .attr("dy", ".35m")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(function(d) { return d; });

        });
    };

    updateMultiData(initial_csv_url);

    $(document).on("click", "button.update_d3_csv", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var new_info = $("#id_date_form").serialize(),
            new_multi_csv_url = "{% url blahblah %}?" + new_info;
        updateMultiData(new_multi_csv_url);
        console.log(new_multi_csv_url);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving a function to `.data()` that tells it how to compare elements? By default, it matches elements by index, so as long as you never give a shorter array, nothing will be in the `.exit()` selection.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff What do you mean?

Comment: When you pass an array to `.data()`, d3 tries to match the elements in the array with the data that is there already. By default, it does this using the index within the array. That is, the first element in the new array will match the first element that you passed in previously -- regardless of what the actual elements are. The `.exit()` selection contains elements that don't match any existing elements, but if you always pass in arrays of the same length, everything will be matched.

Comment: Thing is, I'm not passing in a matching array at all- in fact, I go from having an array of 5-6 rows to only 1 row.

The code runs pretty much exactly as you see it above. If you look for person_name, you'll see the major points of where the data is put in- and you'll see that it loads the brand-new .data(data). And right below it, it does the same with d.tasks.

All of this is run anytime I hit a button- with different sets of data depending on the select box up near the top.

So if it's being given the data the same way each time, how is it not comprehending the change?

Comment: Have you tried printing the `.exit()` selection (and maybe the other ones as well) to see if they contain what you would expect?

Comment: If you add `console.log(svg.selectAll(".name").data(data).exit());`, does it log the list of elements you want to remove?

Comment: To be more exact- what I get back seems to be an array where the first element is another array with a length of 0, with a parentNode of g.[object SVGAnimatedString]. Then it seems to go on into the  __proto__ stuff.

Answer (score 3):

In your example above it seems that the entered nodes have no defined class.  Any subsequent `d3.selectAll(".name")` will return an empty selection and all data elements will show up under `.enter()` method.

You might want to try assigning the corresponding classname every time entering nodes are appended:

```
.enter().append("g").classed("name",true)
```

You might also want to consider using the second argument of `.data()` to define a unique identifier (key) for each datapoint, ensuring that correct elements are exited on each update, if the order is different.
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data

In your code "name" property could probably be used as a key:

```
var person_name = svg.selectAll(".name")
            .data(data,function(d) { return d.name; })
```

Finally I notice that you are appending the axes inside the update function.  This means a new set of axes will be appended on every update on top of the previous ones.  You might want to move those out to the top level.

Comment: Holy hell, this sounds like it could be exactly the issue!

As to the Axes- is it possible to change what the axes are, and have them exited along with the rest of the data? Part of the reason that I have them in there, is specifically to change scale, and so that I can easily put a new type of graph in, in a similar way(a date graph, still using stacked bars, because of the data given that makes line graphs unwieldy).

Comment: d3.svg.axis() is quite clever in this regard.  If axis objects exist in the selection, they are modified, and if they don't exist they are created.   You can therefore .call(xAxis) and .call(yAxis) repeatedly.    My only concern was that you are manually appending the very G containers on every update.      Try moving that append og containers to the top level and give each G a corresponding class (i.e. attr("class","x axis").   Then in update you do: svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis) .....