# d3.js custom layout exit() not working

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to build a Windows Explorer like hierarchical visualization. As I want to compute the x and y coordinates manually, I created a custom layout based on the first example described here:
[Custom layout in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495664/custom-layout-in-d3-js)

My layout function looks like this:

```js
function myTreeLayout(data) {
   var nodes = [];   // or reuse data directly depending on layout
   //load all nodes and their subnodes:
   var coreelement=data;
   coreelement.x=0;
   coreelement.y=0;
   positions(coreelement,0);
   //nodes.push(coreelement); //core element
   
   function child_recursion(element) {
       nodes.push(element);
       if (element.children!=null){
       element.children.forEach(function(child) {
           child_recursion(child);});
   };
   }
   child_recursion(coreelement);
   return nodes;
}
    
      function positions(d,pos_y) { //pos_y is the target position (y) of the element
      var sum_y;
      sum_y=rowheight; //the sum of all vertical space used by that element
      if (d.parent!=null) 
          {d.x=d.parent.x+10;}
      else
          { d.x=0;}
      d.y=pos_y;
    if (d.children) {
          d.children.forEach(function(child) {
              child.parent=d;
              sum_y+=positions(child,pos_y+sum_y);
          });
    }
    return sum_y;
  }
```

The computation of the coordinates works fine. I then bind the data using the following code:

```js
d3.json("data/kdsf-neu.json", function(error, data) {

  root = data;
  root.x0 = 0;
  root.y0 = 0;



  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});


function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = myTreeLayout(root);
  /*,links = tree.links(nodes);*/

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node_coltree")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.Nodeid;
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").classed("g.node_coltree", true)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return 0;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return 0;
    })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", rowheight - 2)
    .attr("class", function(d) {

      var codearray = jQuery.makeArray(d.tags);

      if ($.inArray(tags.Extended, codearray) >= 0) {
        return 'erweiterungsteil_Fill';
      } else if ($.inArray(tags.NotIncluded, codearray) >= 0) {
        return 'nichtAufgenommen_Fill';
      } else if ($.inArray(tags.Optional, codearray) >= 0) {
        return 'optional_Fill';
      } else if ($.inArray(tags.obligatorischWennVorhanden, codearray) >= 0) {
        return 'obligatorisch_Fill';
      } else if ($.inArray(tags.teilweiserForschungsbezug, codearray) >= 0) {
        return 'pubSchale2_Fill';
      } else if ($.inArray(tags.PublikationenSchale2, codearray) >= 0) {
        return 'pubSchale2_Fill';
      } else if ($.inArray(tags.Included, codearray) >= 0) {
        return 'aufgenommen_Fill';
      } else {
        return "#FEFEFE";
      }
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      updatedetails(d);
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return 12;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return 7;
    })

  .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      updatedetails(d);
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      
    });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

}
```

When I start the script, the elements are located at the right positions:

*(As I am not allowed to post images, here a link:)*

When I click on an element, however, the exit function does not seem to work:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3phyu3tx9m13ydt/2.PNG?dl=0

After clicking on an element, the sub-elements are located at the appropriate target positions, but the old elements are not exiting. 
I tried to stay close to the example for coltree, therefore I am also completely recalculating the whole tree after each click:

```
function update(source) {
// Compute the new tree layout.
var nodes = myTreeLayout(root);
```

I already checked the nodes element, it holds only the desired elements after the click. I therefore suspect, that there is some problem with the exit function and the custom layout.

**Related questions:**
My problem might be related to this question:

[D3.js exit() not seeming to get updated information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522661/d3-js-exit-not-seeming-to-get-updated-information)

Therefore, I followed the steps there:

1. I use a custom (externally computed single) index when calling data:

   ```
   .data(nodes , function(d) { return d.Nodeid; });
   ```
2. I added the classed function when appending the node:

   ```
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").classed("g.node_coltree",true)
   ```

Still, the elements stay in the graph - none are exiting.

Do I need to add something to the layout function, that d3 knows how to work with exiting elements? Or is something else wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

---

EDIT: Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasRiechert/nhgejcy0/8/

When clicking on the root node, all sub-elements should disappear. Similarly, when opening a node, the elements should be moving. Both does not seem to happen.

Comment: Can you put together a minimal example, including your data, in either a snippet or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a fairly simple mistake in your code.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhgejcy0/11/

The only difference is:

```
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").classed("node_coltree", true)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x;
    })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y;
    })
       .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
```

Specifically, the first line was changed from:

```
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").classed("g.node_coltree", true)
```

to:

```
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").classed("node_coltree", true)
```

In your version, you were using `classed(...)` to add a class to your nodes of `g.node_coltree`, but you were selecting using `.node_coltree`, which didn't match, so your code just kept adding more and more `g` elements to the svg.  Your `enter` selection contained a new `g` element for each item in your `nodes` array.  This meant that your `update` and `exit` selections were always empty, resulting in nothing being removed.

I found this by inspecting the DOM and seeing that a new list of `g` elements was being appended every time a node was collapsed or expanded.  If the selections were working properly, this wouldn't happen.  It was then just a matter of tracking down whether the selection was wrong, or whether you were appending a different attribute when you created the nodes.  In this case, it looks like the attribute was created incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks alot for the clarification and explanaition!